# Modify parents dict() argument in child definition

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a class A:

```
class A:
    list_attribute = ['foo', 'bar']
    dict_attribute = {'foo': 'bar'}
```

A is extended by B, and in B I want to add elements to `list_attribute` in the declaration of the class, it is pretty easy

```
class B(A):
    list_attribute = A.list_attribute + ['foobar', 'barfoo']
```

My question is, how can I add elements to the `dict_attribute` the same way I did for the `list_attribute` (in the attribute definition, and not in the `__init__`), since dicts don't support the `+` operator ?

Thanks in advance and have a great day!

Comment: `dict_attribute.update(new_dict)`

Comment: dict_attribute.update( {'foobar': 'barfoo' })

Comment: @VineethSai **No!** That will update `A.dict_attribute`. You have to make a copy for `B`.

Comment: or dict_attribute['foobar'] = 'barfoo'...

Comment: @Serge Also **no**!

Comment: @Aran-Fey Oh yes!. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: ok ... B.dict_attribute = {'foobar': 'barfoo' }.update(A.dict_attribute)

Comment: @Serge the update method doesn't return the dict, so it can't be used in the attribute definition

Comment: for one liner dict(d2.items() + d1.items())

Comment: Although I used the solution given in the question linked by @Aran-Fey, this works too indeed, thanks :)